# How to Position the Icon on the upper right corner of the picture

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, expand

Goal:
This expand icon should be on the upper right corner of the picture no matter what size of the picture in relation to responsive design and max size.

Problem:
I have tried so solve it but unfortunately I failed.

Info:
*Please also take account to responsive design
*I'm using bootstrap v3

Thank you!

```css
.expand-position-for-picture {
  border-radius: 22px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 12px 13px 10px 14px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-transition: background .3s;
  transition: background .3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<a href="http://www.partycity.com/images/products/en_us/gateways/candy-2015/candy-by-type/candy-by-type-lollipops.jpg" class="frame img-responsive" title="">
  <img src="http://www.partycity.com/images/products/en_us/gateways/candy-2015/candy-by-type/candy-by-type-lollipops.jpg" class="frame img-responsive">
  <div class="expand-position-for-picture"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
  </div>
</a>





<a href="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4805d33e-a884-4884-b908-7747387bf366/d559cb5e-ca7f-41ae-8827-91d6ef82866b.jpg" class="frame img-responsive" title="">
  <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4805d33e-a884-4884-b908-7747387bf366/d559cb5e-ca7f-41ae-8827-91d6ef82866b.jpg" class="frame img-responsive">
  <div class="expand-position-for-picture"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
  </div>
</a>


http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4805d33e-a884-4884-b908-7747387bf366/d559cb5e-ca7f-41ae-8827-91d6ef82866b.jpg

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because your icon is position absolute, top and right are relative to its offset parent. Have you tried not setting top and right, instead use a negative left margin to pull the icon back over the picture.

Comment: upper right of which image out of 3 used in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

```css
a.frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.expand-position-for-picture {
  border-radius: 22px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 12px 13px 10px 14px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-transition: background .3s;
  transition: background .3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="http://www.partycity.com/images/products/en_us/gateways/candy-2015/candy-by-type/candy-by-type-lollipops.jpg" class="frame img-responsive" title="">
  <img src="http://www.partycity.com/images/products/en_us/gateways/candy-2015/candy-by-type/candy-by-type-lollipops.jpg" class="frame img-responsive">
  <div class="expand-position-for-picture"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4805d33e-a884-4884-b908-7747387bf366/d559cb5e-ca7f-41ae-8827-91d6ef82866b.jpg" class="frame img-responsive" title="">
  <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4805d33e-a884-4884-b908-7747387bf366/d559cb5e-ca7f-41ae-8827-91d6ef82866b.jpg" class="frame img-responsive">
  <div class="expand-position-for-picture"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span>
  </div>
</a>
```